# stat(2) and EINTR

Tags: c, unix, posix

There are some syscall-backed i/o functions (I recently found at least two: `stat()` and `mkdir()` but nearly sure that there are more) that don't have EINTR in possible errno values according to POSIX, but surely may block due to busy disks or due to network-mounted filesystem.

I suspect that there may be slightly POSIX-incompliant implementations returning EINTR from these functions, especially on network filesystems. How likely is that? Is there any point to check `stat()` for EINTR or can I be absolutely sure that this syscall can't be interrupted?

*update*
As noted in answer and comment, POSIX 2.3 allows something:

> Implementations may generate error numbers listed here under circumstances other than those described, if and only if all those error conditions can always be treated identically to the error conditions as described in this volume of POSIX.1-2017. Implementations shall not generate a different error number from one required by this volume of POSIX.1-2017 for an error condition described in this volume of POSIX.1-2017, but may generate additional errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function.

But there is one important thing: `EINTR` in fact is not a *error* condition (it is not a failure from any point of view), and its proper handling will always require some special code.

Example to show what I mean: let's imagine `stat()` returns POSIX-undocumented `ECONNRESET` from NFS handler. This error code is not documented but it can't make any harm: we know that syscall failed for some reason, and our error handler probably don't care what exact error happened since all of them means failure. `EINTR` is completely different story.

Comment: Even if they do, I don't think it's a POSIX compliance violation.  [POSIX 2.3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) says: "Implementations may generate error numbers listed here under circumstances other than those described, if and only if all those error conditions can always be treated identically to the error conditions as described in this volume of POSIX.1-2017."  And it should be true that an EINTR return from `stat()` means that a signal interrupted the call, and you can try it again.

Answer (score 2):

In section 2.3 on [Error Numbers](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03) in the "System Interfaces: General Information" part of [POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), you can find:

> Implementations may support additional errors not included in this list, may generate errors included in this list under circumstances other than those described here, or may contain extensions or limitations that prevent some errors from occurring.
>
> The ERRORS section on each reference page specifies which error conditions shall be detected by all implementations (*"shall fail"*) and which may be optionally detected by an implementation (*"may fail"*). If no error condition is detected, the action requested shall be successful. If an error condition is detected, the action requested may have been partially performed, unless otherwise stated.
>
> Implementations may generate error numbers listed here under circumstances other than those described, if and only if all those error conditions can always be treated identically to the error conditions as described in this volume of POSIX.1-2017. Implementations shall not generate a different error number from one required by this volume of POSIX.1-2017 for an error condition described in this volume of POSIX.1-2017, but may generate additional errors unless explicitly disallowed for a particular function.
>
> Each implementation shall document, in the conformance document, situations in which each of the optional conditions defined in POSIX.1-2017 is detected. The conformance document may also contain statements that one or more of the optional error conditions are not detected.

It seems to me that the first quoted paragraph allows `EINTR` to be generated under circumstances such as you describe.

Comment: This seems to be relevant but i'm not completely sure. Added more text to the question.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of 'not an error condition'.  From my perspective, EINTR ***does*** indicate an error — an interrupt happened before the system call could be completed, so the system call didn't complete what it was asked to do, so that is an error situation.  It isn't necessarily clear what state things are in after the interrupt. However, I/O operations that don't complete either return a short count for the data read or written or return an error and set `errno` to EINTR if there was no I/O completed.  There are some restartable system calls.

Answer (score 2):

If we take Linux NFS as an example: [NFS doesn't claim full POSIX compliance](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2006/ols2006v2-pages-59-72.pdf).

Furthermore, the default options are the closest thing to POSIX-compliance you get with NFS, and in particular, you don't get `EINTR`.

However if you mount with certain options e.g. `soft`, `timeo`, `retrans`, `intr`, then you are actively asking the filesystem to alter the behavior to something that might not be POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 1):

`stat` is not a "syscall"; it's a system interface; that is, a standard library function. It's implementation may involve syscalls, but it certainly doesn't have to; it might be implemented only using other system interfaces, whether documented or not.

It certainly might block. But that doesn't mean that a process blocked on a call to `stat` will wake up and return something other than the requested file stat just because it is sent an interrupt. And the implementation does not have its hands tied by being a system interface, either. If the implementation involves a call to some other blocking system interface which returns `EINTR`, the correct thing for the `stat` implementation to do is to retry whatever call was interrupted. Nothing stops it from doing that.

If it were to return failure with `errno` set to `EINTR`, that would certainly be a violation of Posix (imho), but I'm certainly not going to venture out on that wobbly limb labeled "all unices are perfectly posix". If you wanted to check for the `EINTR` after failure, just in case the local OS is not perfectly posix, I certainly wouldn't criticize you. But I actually don't think it's a very likely result.